# Why am I receiving Missing Keyword SQL/CFML Error?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, cfml

I'm an experiencing an issue with a SQL query inside a CFML application. The code is suppose to clear out a DB, loop through a provided csv, and insert rows based on the csv's data into DB. However, I receive an error saying that I have a missing keyword on the line after INSERT ALL. It seems like maybe an update to ColdFusion was introduced and it effectively broke the code because it was working perfectly fine up until this point.

```
<cfset fileContent = fileRead( localFile ) />

<!--- Remove trailing line breaks and carriage returns. --->
<cfset fileContent = reReplace(
    fileContent,
    "[\r\n]+$",
    "",
    "all"
    ) />

<cfquery datasource="cs1_webdata_dsn" name="truncateTemp">
    truncate table ftp_temp
</cfquery>

<p>Success: Deleted all records in ftp_temp table</p>
<cfflush>

    <cfquery datasource="cs1_webdata_dsn" name="insertIntoTemp">

        INSERT ALL 
        <cfloop list="#fileContent#" delimiters="#chr(10)#" item="record" index="i">
            <cfif i gt 1>


                <!--- Remove trailing line breaks and carriage returns. --->
                <cfset record = reReplace(
                    record,
                    "[\r\n]+$",
                    "",
                    "all"
                    ) />

                <cfset rowData = ListToArray(record, "#chr(9)#")>
                INTO ftp_temp (LOTID, PARTNAME, LOTTYPE, WAFERS)
                VALUES          
                (
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#rowData[1]#">,
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#rowData[2]#">,
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#rowData[3]#">,
                    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#rowData[4]#">
                )
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>   
        SELECT * FROM dual
    </cfquery>

    <p>Success: Loaded /WDT/WebDisp.csv file contents into ftp_temp table</p>
<cfflush>
```

I've tried rearranging the query so that the query is inside of the loop vs the loop being inside of the query and it worked, but it didn't populate the DB at all.

Comment: It may or may not be relevant that you refer to a .csv file which implies comma separators but specify a tab delimiter when you set your row data.

Comment: Dump put the values to see what they are and add them to your question. No way to answer otherwise.

Comment: The error should be showing you the SQL that you're creating and that the DB has tried to run. Look at it. What's wrong with it? Reason as to why it's wrong. We can't help you really cos you ain't shown us what it is, nor have you shown us what the exact error is. This is table stakes for us being able to help. NB: you *really* shouldn't be mixing DB interaction with UI code like that. It's a pretty significant application design anti-pattern.

Comment: What @AdamCameron said. There's likely a character in the text of the CSV file that is causing the error. It always worked before because that character wasn't in the previous files. The SQL in the error output should point you toward the culprit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll review the .csv file and compare it against a known working copy. As for the ANTI pattern, thanks for the heads up. While it was written well before me, I figured it was alright since it only logged that it completed an action. and at that it was only something the admin could see.